# solving sum- function of an infinit series(real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis

find the sum-function of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}ne^{-nx}$ on [1,b], (b real constant).
It happened that i don't know how to begin to solve this problem.

i know that $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$

am wondering what approach to apply.
Help pls,

thanks

Comment: $ne^{-nx} = \frac{d}{dx}e^{-nx}$. You should probably compute $\sum_n e^{-nx}$ and use the theorem about derivation of a series of functions.

Comment: Combine what Siminore wrote and the fact that you can replace $1/e^x$ by $y$.

Comment: sorry pls, is not too clear, can i have some further hint to simplify it. thanks alot

Comment: want to be sure if $-e^{-3x}(1-e^{-x})^{-2}$ is the answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-nx}=1+e^{-x}+e^{-2x}+e^{-3x}+\ldots=\frac{e^x}{e^x-1}
$$
by the formula for the geometric series with base $e^{-x}$. Now differentiate:
$$
-e^{-x}-2e^{-2x}-3e^{-3x} -\ldots = -\sum_{n=1}^\infty n e^{-nx} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{e^x}{e^x-1} = -\frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}.
$$
Hence
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty n e^{-nx} = \frac{e^x}{(e^x-1)^2}.
$$
See also [the result by WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5Bn%20Exp%5B-n%20x%5D,%7Bn=1,Infinity%7D%5D).